# How to initialize a char*[] array?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
int main(){
int n;
cin>>n;
char *str[40];
str=new char [10000][40]; //I don't know how to initialize this array
std::map<char*,int> system;
int i,j;
//solving Question 4C @ Codeforces
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>str[i];
}
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    int count=0;
    for(std::map<char*,int>::iterator iter=system.begin();iter!=system.end();iter++){
        if(strcmp(iter->first,str[i])==0){
            count=++iter->second;
        }
        else if(strcmp(str[i],iter->first)>0){
            break;
        }
    }
    if(count==0){
        system[str[i]]=1;
        cout<<"OK"<<endl;
    }
    else{
        char *strint;
        strint=new char[5];
        strint=convert(count);
        strcat(str[i],strint);
        cout<<str[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

}

Question: http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/4/C

I am looking for a way that I could put the char array as an element of the map to help solving the scenario,
however,
I ended up with either screwing up the map.insert function when I declare str[n][40] as str, system as ,
(Could somebody please explain why map.insert(str[i],1) won't work in this case? It would be sweet to clarify the concepts)
or in this case,
fails to initialize the char*str[40] array.

I wonder what is the legit way to do this?

Comment: so you don't like `std::string` then ;-) ? You code currently leaks like a colander.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::vector<std::string>v(40)`?

Comment: Using pointers as keys in a `std::map` is usually not what you want to do. Why don't you use `std::vector` and `std::string`? There's no need to program like it's 1969 any more.

Comment: I am used to char[] as my school secondary school taught me C, and I have just recently transferred to C++. Perhaps I have overlooked the benefits of using string and vector. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char *str[40];
str=new char [10000][40]; //I don't know how to initialize this array
```

`str` is an array. You can assign something to values in an array, but arrays themselves cannot be assigned to. You are probably trying to do:

```
char *str[40];

for (size_t i=0; i<40; ++i)
   str[i]=new char [10000];
```

Still, in modern C++ one rarely needs to do `new` and `delete` in the first place; instead modern C++ code uses containers. Speaking of containers:

```
std::map<char*,int> system;
```

This is not going to lead to anything good. A `std::map` literally compares key by their values. So:

```
char *foo1=new char[40];

strcpy(foo1, "foo");

system[foo1]=0;

char *foo2=new char[40];

strcpy(foo2, "foo");

auto iter=system.find(foo2);
```

Do you think that `find()` here, will find this element? Of course not, because it's a different pointer value.

Although maps that use raw pointers as keys are valid C++, it's not very obvious how to use them correctly.

In conclusion, you should spend more time studying and learning how to use various containers. Here, `std::vector` should be used instead of futzing around with `new` and `delete`. And `std::string` should be used instead of `char *` as the map key. You'll be surprisd to learn that the end result will be smaller and easier to read, and understand.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I shall look further into the string container.